# MS Access Move visible selected cell to first cell of active table active row

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to position the active/selected cell on the active record in an open MS Access table. No forms are involved - I am just looking at a normal table in DataSheet view. I need VBA to move the selected cell up, down, to the first cell on the record, and so on.

I have tried `SendKeys {Up},{Home}`, etc, but that doesn't move the selected cell.

Is there a VBA way to move the active/selected cell on an open table in DataSheet view mode? Thank you.

```
Sub MoveSelectedCell()
Dim tbl As AccessObject, tblname As String
tblname = Application.CurrentObjectName
' I need to move the selected cell that receives keyboard input.
' SendKeys does nothing
' I need something like Selection.Field = ActiveRecord.Field(0)
'
' I can't find Selection.Move like in Word/Excel VBA
' Is there a way to move the selected cell in Access? Thank you

' SendKeys "{Home}"
End Sub
```

Comment: No, Access tables do not have 'cells' that can be moved. Access tables are not spreadsheets. Word tables are like spreadsheets but Access tables are not. Databases manage records, not cells. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Tables are not meant to program against, forms are. If you have a form in datasheet view, selecting a specific field is trivial.

Comment: @June7 I know that datasheet views are not meant to be user forms. But as a developer, I can use them in any way that makes my life easier, yes? There are no forms in my application yet - I'm still working on the database models and operations in C# code. I frequently scroll down to the new record to experiment with values, and it gets tedious. I'm trying to write a VBA macro that puts the editing cursor where I need it. Yes, it's trivial to click a cell when my hand is on the mouse over the cell. But getting there is tedious. Maybe I'll have to write VBA Access forms to make it easier.

Comment: Yes, use tables as you see fit. AFAIK, what you described is not possible to accomplish. Build a form bound to table and use code to set focus to new record row or have form set to open only for new record input and not display existing records.

Comment: I just thought Access (with full VBA underneath) should be able to move the editing cursor around in a datasheet view. It can activate tables and display them in datasheet view, move the cursor to a record in a view, so why not move to a field column as well? I guess I was mistaken in thinking there would be a way to move the "Selection.Cell" in a datasheet. Oh well. Thank you for your interest.